# Create link (edge) between widget in Flutter with Page View

Tags: flutter, widget, containers, flutter-pageview

I would like to know if you have a suggestion to create link between widget similarly to [graphview](https://pub.dev/packages/graphview).

My idea is to have a [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) where children are Columns. In that columns, have some container and create a line between a container from Column A to container from Column B.

[image]

Have you an idea to achieve that ?

Thanks

[graphview](https://pub.dev/packages/graphview).